# How come Maven's validate and verify phases execute without goals bound to them?

Tags: builds, maven

Maven's documentation states the following: ["If a build phase has no goals bound to it, that build phase will not execute"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

However, according to the same documentation, [the *validate* and *verify* phases do not seem to have goals bound to them](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.5/maven-core/default-bindings.html).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found [the exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940552/no-plugin-goals-bound-to-a-maven-phase) answered on Stack Overflow and, according to it, ...

- both of the above statements are correct
- the *validate* and *verify* phases don't have goals bound to them **by default**
- the *validate* and *verify* phases will only execute if the POM binds a plugin's goal to them